# Force Stop Error at RunTime MySQL and form validator Android

Tags: android, validation

I have a project that

1. Gets user details
2. Sends user details to a MySQL server

Now I want to make my EditTexts not empty .

Or its characters are more than 3.

My code works when a user sends invalid or empty details.

But when all EditTexts are filled correctly  my application show a ForceStop error.

```
public class Register extends Activity {
    public EditText name, lastName, phoneNumber, email, username, password, namee, lastNamee, phoneNumberr, usernamee, passwordd;
    private FButton reg_btn_login;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://mojtabaapp.esy.es/register.php";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    // baresi edit text ha
    public boolean AyaVorodYSahihBood() {
        namee = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_name);
        lastNamee = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_famili);
        phoneNumberr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_phone);
        usernamee = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user);
        passwordd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
        boolean n, l, ph, u, p;
        n = name.getText().toString().length() > 3;
        l = lastNamee.getText().toString().length() > 3;
        ph = phoneNumberr.getText().toString().length() == 11;
        u = usernamee.getText().toString().length() > 5;
        p = passwordd.getText().toString().length() > 5;
        if (n | l | ph | u | p) {
            return false;

        } else return true;

    }
    private boolean isNetworkConnected() { // check internet connection
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni == null) {
            // There are no active networks.
            return false;
        } else return true;
    }
    public void NamayeshBedeDialog() {
        new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
            .title(string.title_dialog)
            .content(string.dialog_content)
            .positiveText(string.bashe)
        //   .negativeText(string.mikham_brm)
        .show();
        new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
            .callback(new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback() {@Override
            public void onPositive(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                // dialog.dismiss();
            }@Override
            public void onNegative(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                //finish();
            }
        });
    }
    //method namayesh dialog email eshteba
    public void Namayesh_dialog_email_eshteba() {
        AlertDialog.Builder abb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        abb.setTitle(R.string.title_dialog);
        abb.setMessage(R.string.Email_eshteba_ast);
        abb.setPositiveButton(talash_mojadad, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
        });
        abb.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        abb.show();
    }
    //method namayesh shomare eshteba
    public void Namayesh_dialog_shomare_eshteba() {
        AlertDialog.Builder abbb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        abbb.setTitle(R.string.title_dialog);
        abbb.setMessage(R.string.phonenumber_is_incorrect);
        abbb.setPositiveButton(talash_mojadad, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
        });
        abbb.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        abbb.show();
    }@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        // tarif ha
        name = (com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_name);
        lastName = (com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_famili);
        phoneNumber = (com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_phone);
        reg_btn_login = (FButton) findViewById(R.id.reg_btn_login);
        email = (com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_mail);
        // aya addres email sahih mibashad ?
        reg_btn_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isNetworkConnected() == false) {
                    NamayeshBedeDialog();
                    return;
                }
                if (AyaVorodYSahihBood()) {
                    NamayeshBedeDialog();
                    return;
                }
                new CreateUser().execute();
            }
        });
        if (isNetworkConnected() == false) {

            NamayeshBedeDialog();
        }
    }
    class CreateUser extends AsyncTask < String, String, String > {
        boolean failure = false;@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("..???? ??? ??? ????");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String NAME = name.getText().toString();
            String LASTNAME = lastName.getText().toString();
            String MAIL = email.getText().toString();
            int PHONE = Integer.parseInt(phoneNumber.getText().toString());
            int cash = 0;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List < NameValuePair > params = new ArrayList < NameValuePair > ();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", NAME));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", LASTNAME));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emailaddres", MAIL));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phonenumber", String.valueOf(PHONE)));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usercash", String.valueOf(cash)));
                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                //Posting user data to script
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
                // full json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
                // jon success element
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                    finish();
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null) {
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_register, menu);
        return true;
    }@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```